# behavior differences between firebase realtime database and firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

i used to use realtime database on firebase and i always used update which used to create if the node is missing. So for the below code:

```
 async updateUser(uid: string, payload: any) {
    const userDocRef = doc(this.firestore, 'users/' + uid );
    return updateDoc(userDocRef, {"email": "xxx@moblize.it"});
  }
```

Realtime db will simply create a new node with uid if does not exist or else update. However, doing the same with Firestore db it gives me error as

```
api.js?onload=__iframefcb905117:29 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: No document to update: projects/baniya-38d78/databases/(default)/documents/users/vdZMeCkTfrhd12j1CWyR9eGhra12
FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/baniya-38d78/databases/(default)/documents/users/vdZMeCkTfrhd12j1CWyR9eGhra12
```

is that how firestore db works and i have to always check if it exist to decide create or update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a create-or-update operation on Firestore, use `set` with merge options as shown in the second code sample in the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document). In your case that'd be:

```
setDoc(userDocRef, {"email": "xxx@moblize.it"}, { merge: true });
```